# complicated join in spark: rdd elements have many key-value pairs

Tags: join, rdd, pyspark

I'm new to spark and trying to find a way to integrate information from one rdd into another, but their structures don't lend themselves to a standard join function

I have on rdd of this format:

```
[{a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1},
 {a:a2, b:b2, c:[5,6,7,8], d:d2}]
```

and another of this format:

```
[{1:x1},{2,x2},{3,x3},{4,x4},{5,x5},{6,x6},{7,x7},{8,x8}]
```

I want to match the values in the second rdd to their keys in the first rdd (which are in a list value in the c key).  I know how to manipulate them once they're there, so I'm not too concerned about the final output, but I'd maybe like to see something like this:

```
[{a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4],c0: [x1,x2,x3,x4], d:d1},
 {a:a2, b:b2, c:[5,6,7,8],c0: [x5,x6,x7,x8], d:d2}]
```

or this:

```
[{a:a1, b:b1, c:[(1,x1),(2,x2),(3,x3),(4,x4)], d:d1},
 {a:a2, b:b2, c:[(5,x5),(6,x6),(7,x7),(8,x8)], d:d2}]
```

or anything else that can match the keys in the second rdd with the values in the first.  I considered making the second rdd into a dictionary, which I know how to work with, but I just think my data is too large for that.

Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think there is little you can do...you may use cartesian but this would be very inefficent...

Answer (score 1):

`join` after `flatMap`, or `cartesian` makes too many shuffles.

One of the possible solutions is to use `cartesian` after `groupBy` with `HashPartitioner`.

(Sorry, this is `scala` code)

```
val rdd0: RDD[(String, String, Seq[Int], String)]
val rdd1: RDD[(Int, String)]

val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(rdd0.partitions.size)

// here is the point!
val grouped = rdd1.groupBy(partitioner.getPartition(_))

val result = rdd0.cartesian(grouped).map { case (left, (_, right)) =>
    val map = right.toMap
    (left._1, left._2, left._4) -> left._3.flatMap(v => map.get(v).map(v -> _))
}.groupByKey().map { case (key, value) =>
    (key._1, key._2, value.flatten.toSeq, key._3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that `rdd1` is the input containing `{a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}` and `rdd2` has tuples `[(1, x1), (2, x2), (3, x3), (4, x4), (5, x5), (6, x6), (7, x7), (8, x8)]`. I will also assume that all values in the "c" field in `rdd1` can be found in `rdd2`. If not, you need to change some of the code below.

I sometimes have to solve this type of problem. If `rdd2` is small enough, I typically do a map-side join, where I first broadcast the object and then do a simple lookup.

```
def augment_rdd1(line, lookup):
    c0 = []
    for key in line['c']:
        c0.append(lookup.value[key])
    return c0

lookup = sc.broadcast(dict(rdd2.collect()))
output = rdd1.map(lambda line: (line, augment_rdd1(line, lookup)))
```

If `rdd2` is too large to be broadcasted, what I normally do is use a `flatMap` to map every row of `rdd1` to as many rows as there are elements in the "c" field, e.g. `{a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}` would be mapped to

- `(1, {a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1})`
- `(2, {a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1})`
- `(3, {a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1})`
- `(4, {a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1})`

The flatMap is

```
flat_rdd1 = rdd1.flatMap(lambda line: [(key, line) for key in line['c'])])
```

Then, I would join with rdd2 to get an RDD which has:

- `({a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}, x1)`
- `({a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}, x2)`
- `({a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}, x3)`
- `({a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}, x4)`

The join is the following:

```
rdd2_tuple = rdd2.map(lambda line: line.items())
joined_rdd = flat_rdd1.join(rdd2_tuple).map(lambda x: x[1])
```

Finally, all you need to do is a `groupByKey` to get `({a:a1, b:b1, c:[1,2,3,4], d:d1}, [x1, x2, x3, x4])`:

```
result = joined_rdd.groupByKey()
```

Comment: This is awesome. I wish i knew how to bookmark it beyond writing a comment.